# How to access an exact XML node and not the value of it in an XSL stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt

Ok,

So in my XML file I have an image node:

`<img alt="Green arrow" src="green-arrow-up-icone-5011-48.png"/>`

Now I want to display this in my webpage using XSL:

If I use `<xsl:value-of select = "//img"/>`

(there is only one image), I don't get anything because the "value of" img is nothing as it has no nodes in it. How do I make XSL just take that node as it is and just display it on the webpage?

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:copy-of select="expression"/>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_copy-of.asp

Answer (score 1):

There is `xsl:copy-of` e.g. `<xsl:copy-of select="img"/>` respectively `<xsl:template match="img"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:template>`.